# Configure route 53 to forward incoming email to Sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid, amazon-route53, incoming-mail

I have added a MX record to my route 53 so that I can receive email when customer sends email to my domain using support@mydomain.com etc. I have webhook POST that suppose to get the request and parse it.

I have added an MX record in route 35 as send grid official document suggested.

10 mx.sendgrid.net.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/parsing-email/setting-up-the-inbound-parse-webhook

During testing it keeps giving me Address not found with the response

"DNS Error: DNS type 'mx' lookup of mydomain.com responded with code NOERROR DNS type 'mx' lookup of mydomain.com had no relevant answers. DNS type 'aaaa' lookup of mydomain.com responded with code NOERROR DNS type 'aaaa' lookup of mydomain.com had no relevant answers. DNS type 'a' lookup of mydomain.com responded with code NOERROR DNS type 'a' lookup of mydomain.com had no relevant answers."

It seems like route53 is not even able to forward incoming email to sendgrid at first place.

And when run dig mydomain.com I see the following response

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> mx mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55194
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When creating a new MX record in your Route53 hosted zone, make sure you leave the *subdomain (record name)* textbox empty.

   [image]
2. Once this record is added, you can go to [MX Toolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/), and do a lookup on your domain. It should display the same MX record value that you just added above.

> Above all, ensure that your Route53 domain is accessible. That is, if you purchased the domain from a third party, such as GoDaddy, make sure you modify the name-servers to point the domain to Route53.